# Can I multiply an element of a group to an element of a different group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question goes like this:

> Write down a group table for the groups C4 and C2 x C2. For every element a in C4 and C2 x C2 determine the smallest positive integer m such that $ m\cdot a$ equals the identity element

I managed to sketch the tables for both groups and then I said something like this:

> We know that the set of elements in C4 are {$ \overline 0, \overline1, \overline2 , \overline3 $} and that m $\in$ $\mathbb Z$ and m > 0.
>
> Then for a = $\overline 1$ the right m would be 4 because m $\cdot$ a = $\overline 1$ $\cdot$ 4 = $\overline4$ = $\overline 0$ = identity element. And here m would be the smallest integer.
>
> For a = $\overline 2$ the right m would be 2 because m $\cdot$ a = $\overline 2$ $\cdot$ 2 = $\overline4$ = $\overline 0$ = identity element. And here m would be the smallest integer.

Is this wrong? I mean to multiply an element of a group, i.e C4 with an element of a different group, i.e $\mathbb Z$?
Can you guys provide me with some hints if this is wrong?

Comment: There is no element $\bar 4$, so your last two equalities in each example don't make sense. You are also basically asserting all the equalities without argument, and also asserting that the $m$ you provide is minimal without argument. Admittedly, this whole thing is just an exercise in a completely straightforward and small computation, so the argument is basically going to be "compute and see" anyway.

Comment: @DerekElkins 4 mod 4 = $\overline 0$. I didn't say that $\overline 4$ exists in the set.

Comment: If $\bar 4=\bar 0$ then it certainly *is* in the set. The real point of that comment is that you haven't *defined* what $\bar 4$ means at all. Maybe you have a definition written down, but it is not written in your question. Admittedly, I was interpreting your question as whether the quoted part constitutes a reasonable proof, but you don't actually explicitly ask that. If your question is just whether $m=4$ and $m=2$ are the solutions to those two examples, then yes, they are.

Comment: @DerekElkins What do you suggest I should do then?

Comment: If your goal is to make an informal proof, then, in general, proofs work from definitions, so my suggestion is to define what $\bar 4$ means or realize that it's unnecessary.  More generally, apply definitions everywhere. Your title question does indeed ask for clarity on a definition, but if you didn't know what e.g. $4\cdot\bar 1$ meant, on what basis did you come to the conclusion that it should be $\bar 4$ or $\bar 0$? If you did want to spell out the calculations using the definition given by David Hill, it would look something like ...

Comment: ...  $1\cdot\bar 1=\bar 1$, $2\cdot\bar 1=\bar 1+\bar 1=\bar 2$, $3\cdot\bar 1=\bar 1+\bar 1+\bar 1=\bar 2+\bar 1=\bar 3$, and $4\cdot\bar 1=\bar 1+\bar 1+\bar 1+\bar 1=\bar 3+\bar 1=\bar 0$ where the last equality in each string comes from your multiplication table (i.e. the *definition* of $+$ for this group). By computing the earlier results, we show not only that $4\cdot\bar 1=\bar 0$ but also that no smaller positive integer works which is what we need to show that $4$ is the smallest positive integer that works and not just one integer that happens to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m>0$. You should interpret 
$$
m\cdot a=\underbrace{a+a+\cdots+a}_{\mbox{$m$ times}}
$$
and to extend to negative numbers set $
(-m)\cdot a= m\cdot(-a)$. Of course, $0\cdot a=0$.

Comment: If that is so it means that my approach would be a legit one, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!